# $\pi_1(\mathbb{Q}^2)$ is countable

Tags: algebraic-topology

We know that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2-\mathbb{Q}^2)$ is uncountable, can one conclude that $\pi_1(\mathbb{Q}^2)$ is countable? or maybe $\pi_1(\mathbb{Q}^2)$ is known explicitly-I don't know!

Answer (score 6):

Since $\Bbb{Q}^2$ is totally disconnected, it has trivial fundamental group (for any choice of basepoint).

Comment: sorry! my question was not correct .. i'll edit it know

Comment: ok! so totally disconnected spaces have trivial fundamental group.

Comment: further question: what are the applications of the fact that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2-\mathbb{Q}^2)$ is uncountable ?

Comment: @Rahman: That's a separate question, not a comment on this answer. Ask it as a new question.